# Input not in correct format

Tags: c#, libreadline

I want to read a double value and a integer value from a console application in C#. 
`

```
            int ch = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a random integer");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



           switch (ch)
            {
                case 1:

                    TempServiceRef.Service1Client s1 = new ConsoleTempApplication.TempServiceRef.Service1Client();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature");
                    string n = Console.ReadLine();
                    int param = int.Parse(n);
                    double result = s1.c2f(param);
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;

                case 2:

                    TempServiceRef.Service1Client s2 = new ConsoleTempApplication.TempServiceRef.Service1Client();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature");
                    int param1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    double result1 = s2.f2c(param1);
                    Console.WriteLine(result1);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;

                default:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
            }
            `
```

The console application closes once I try to enter my value for ch. Sometimes it closes after I give a value for temperature. I tried using tryParse and Convert.toInt. But I am not getting any results. Anyone who can help me with this? Further...I am just expecting the user to input only integer values(as an assumption). The tryparse usage in this case is not mandatory right?

Comment: you need to add `Console.ReadLine()` to complete the reading.check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:** You are using the `Console.Read()` method to read the single character from console.but here you need to press the `Enter key` to return the entered value/character as you are using the `Console.Read()` method.so when you press the Enter `Console.ReadLine()` method will get the value Empty string and int.Parse() throws Exception on Empty Strings.

**Solution 1:** you need to add `Console.ReadLine()` after the `Console.Read()` method to read the first character. and then you can proceed.

Try This:

```
            int ch =Console.Read();               
            Console.ReadLine(); //add this statement
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a random integer");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

**Problem 2:** You are tryig to compare the Characters entered from console to numbers directly which does not work as when you read the character from console it will store its ASCII value not direct integer.for example if you enter `1` from console, it will be stored as `49` in integer variable `ch`(ACII code of 1 is 49) so when you compare with 1 it does not match .

**Solution 2:** so you need to match with its character value. so enclose the values within single quotes to match with exact value entered in console.

Try This: enclose 1 and 2 within single quotes

```
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '1':  
                 ---
                 break;
                case '2':
                 -----
                 break;
            }
```

**Complete Code:**

```
        int ch = Console.Read();
        Console.ReadLine();//Add this line to complete reading of a character
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a random integer");
        int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



       switch (ch)
        {
            case '1':

                TempServiceRef.Service1Client s1 = new ConsoleTempApplication.TempServiceRef.Service1Client();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature");
                string n = Console.ReadLine();
                int param = int.Parse(n);
                double result = s1.c2f(param);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;

            case '2':

                TempServiceRef.Service1Client s2 = new ConsoleTempApplication.TempServiceRef.Service1Client();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature");
                int param1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double result1 = s2.f2c(param1);
                Console.WriteLine(result1);
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;

            default:
                Environment.Exit(0);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot....But I figured it out. But it kinda contradicts your answer. The code worked without me having to use the single quotes. I do not know what the reason might be..But http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664749(v=vs.71).aspx also says the same thing. And you were right about the readLine() part. Thank you very much..I think I was comparing the integer itself...not the characters...I think that makes sense